# cannot load ajax content on superslides jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am quite a newbie to jquery,
Actually i am using Superslides plugin [Superslides](http://nicinabox.com/superslides)

for background and using a div in front to load some other page using ajax.
Now the problem is that when i load the page eg. clients page with jquery ajax method it loads fine but then the main page navigation stops working. I mean List items which lets users move to next slide dosen't work.
Maybe the list items in clients page is conflicting with the main page list items as i have been using Li to navigate main page from back slide to next slide.
here is my code

This is how i set up click binding with Li navigation

the jquery code for slide

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.mainMenuListItem').click(function () {
            var currentThumbSel = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $('.slides-pagination a:nth-child(' + currentThumbSel + ')').click();


        });
    });
</script>
```

and the html navigation code is

```
 <div id="mainMenuStrip">
    <ul id="mainMenuList">
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" id="homeMenuListItem" data-id="1">HOME |</li>
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" data-id="2">ABOUT |</li>
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" id="clientsMenuListItem" data-id="3">CLIENTS |</li>
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" data-id="4">HOW WE WORK | </li>
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" data-id="5">OUR PROJECTS |</li>
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" data-id="6">DOWNLOAD TOOLS |</li>
        <li class="mainMenuListItem" data-id="7">CONTACT</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**And now the clients page code is**

```
<style>
    #clientsList {
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 810px;
        height: 460px;

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

        #clientsList li {
            float: left;
            height: 150px;
            margin-left: 4px;
            margin-top: 7px;
            width: 265px;
            background-color: black;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .overlayClient {
        position: absolute;
        height: 150px;
        width: 265px;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: red;
        opacity: 0.7;
        display: none;
    }

    .informationZoom {
        color: white;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 51px;
        margin-left: 115px;
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 38px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //$('#clientsList>li').mouseenter(function() {
        //    $(this).find(".overlayClient").fadeIn(500);




        //});

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$('#clientsList>li').mouseleave(function () {
        //    $(this).find(".overlayClient").fadeOut(500);




        //});

    });

</script>
```

```
<ul id="clientsList">
    <li>

        <div class="overlayClient"><span class="informationZoom">+</span></div>
        <img src="images/clients/eaSports.jpg" />

    </li>
    <li>

        <div class="overlayClient"><span class="informationZoom">+</span></div>
        <img src="images/clients/eaSports.jpg" />

    </li>
    <li>

        <div class="overlayClient"><span class="informationZoom">+</span></div>
        <img src="images/clients/eaSports.jpg" />

    </li>
    <li>

        <div class="overlayClient"><span class="informationZoom">+</span></div>
        <img src="images/clients/eaSports.jpg" />

    </li>
```

**And here is the Ajax Load method**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#clientsMenuListItem').click(function () {

            $('#clientsAjaxContainer').load('clients.html'); 
        });
    });


</script>
```

**you can see that clients page also contains li, maybe some clash with Li??**
Please help me on this.
thanks.

Comment: Added Ajax method at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your Jquery is clashing, try load jquery on main site and dont use it inside the child page.
thanks

Comment: Yes that was the problem, i removed jquery on child and it works. thanks